# Display checked values in jquery multiselect

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, laravel

I am creating an app using laravel + bootstrap and jquery etc. Now I want to make jquery multiselect but I do not know how to display values that I have in database. Can u help me? Here's that what I actually have:

```
<form action="{{ action('Player@store') }}" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
                  {{ csrf_field() }}
              <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-5">
                  <select name="from[]" id="multiselect" class="form-control" size="8" multiple="multiple">
                      <option value="1">Item 1</option>
                      <option value="2">Item 5</option>
                      <option value="2">Item 2</option>
                      <option value="2">Item 4</option>
                      <option value="3">Item 3</option>
                  </select>
              </div>
              <div class="col-xs-2">
                  <button type="button" id="multiselect_rightAll" class="btn btn-block">
                    <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                  </button>
                  <button type="button" id="multiselect_rightSelected" class="btn btn-block">
                  <i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                  <button type="button" id="multiselect_leftSelected" class="btn btn-block">
                    <i class="fa fa-angle-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                  </button>
                  <button type="button" id="multiselect_leftAll" class="btn btn-block">
                    <i class="fa fa-angle-double-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                  </button>
              </div>

              <div class="col-xs-5">
                  <select name="to[]" id="multiselect_to" class="form-control" size="8" multiple="multiple"></select>
              </div>
          </div>

          <script type="text/javascript">
          jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
              $('#multiselect').multiselect();
          });
          </script>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">@lang('main.save')</button>
        </form>
```

Comment: displaying checked values on edit form ?

Comment: Yeah, in to[] place. I mean that should look like value="{{$data->xyz}}" but in  multiselect for multiple values

Comment: Do you have problem for `how to loop on data array` ?

Comment: I have a problem how to display data in to[], but in the same time delete selected options from from